# Wordpress Custom Function on CSV

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I'm trying to run a custom function on a csv import into Wordpress. Basically my csv feed has three different sizes of each image. I'm trying to exclude the 2 lowest quality images based on their directory location. For example

So the only identifier across all 5000 images is that the low quality versions exist in thumbnails & detail directory. I created a custom function to process the delimited image list and exclude urls containing those 2 keywords.

```
    function generate_img_list($list)
      { 
     $html = ''; 
    if ( "" != $list)
    { 
      foreach (explode(';', $list) as $li)
     {    
        if ((strpos($li ,'thumbnail')) || (strpos($li ,'detail')) === false)
        {
        $html .= '<img src="' . $li . '"/>'; 
       }
    }
   } 
  return $html; 
 }
```

For some reason this works only on the first keyword thumbnail but totally ignores the second. I'm pretty sure this should work, but is there any reason why Wordpress might interupt it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"if stringpos 'thumbnail' is not false or stringpos 'detail' is false"

```
if ((strpos($li ,'thumbnail')) || (strpos($li ,'detail')) === false)
```

You might rather want:

"if stringpos 'thumbnail' is not false or stringpos 'detail' is NOT false"

```
if (strpos($li ,'thumbnail') || strpos($li ,'detail'))
```

or

```
if (false !== strpos($li ,'thumbnail') || false !== strpos($li ,'detail'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately they didn't work as required, in actual fact the only urls brought in were the ones containing "thumbnail" & "detail" ... However thanks to your assistance in me understanding it better i decided it would make more sense to only bring in urls containing "gallery" as they are ultimately the only ones i want. So simply used `if (strpos($li ,'gallery'))`